# $_SESSION variables are not accessible within a file

Tags: php, session, web

I have a web server with a particular $_SESSION variable set containing a user ID. I have a particular file (possibly a directory) that I can't seem to access this session variable inside of. My structure looks something like:

```
/root/[this is where I set my session variable].php

/root/subdirectory/[this is where the file is].php
```

Before you ask, yes, I'm using `session_start()` at the top of every page I need this variable in. Now, I've tried var_dump-ing $_SESSION and it returned an empty array. But this variable seems to be accessible everywhere else. What could cause this? Could it be file permissions? Or are $_SESSION variables only accessible within a directory?

Thank you.

ADDITIONAL INFO:

Here's something strange: So the problem I'm having only happens when a file (say, index.php) runs a script from the second file (the one that for whatever reason doesn't have access to the $_SESSION var), but when I go to the file manually (i.e. put the URL in my web browser), the $_SESSION vars return just fine.

Comment: "So the problem I'm having only happens when a file (say, index.php) runs a script from the second file", so how do you run a script from a second file? please include some code.

Answer (score 0):

$_SESSION variables are normally bound to HTTP session, which is identified by the session cookie set to the browser. If you've used directory path while setting the session cookie, session variables are only available in that directory. HTTP traffic monitor will tell that best.

See how to configure the path from http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php:

> void session_set_cookie_params ( int $lifetime [, string $path [,
>   string $domain [, bool $secure = false [, bool $httponly = false ]]]]
>   )

path parameter is what you're interested in. Use '/' for the entire domain if that's what you want.

If you don't want to set the path every time but once for all, use `session.cookie_path` php.ini/.htaccess configuration.

Comment: This returned array(5) {
  ["lifetime"]=>
  int(0)
  ["path"]=>
  string(1) "/"
  ["domain"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["secure"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["httponly"]=>
  bool(false)
}

Answer (score 0):

Try displaying the session cookie parameters to make sure they are ok by running after session_start:

```
var_dump(session_get_cookie_params());
```

If path (or domain) doesn't match the prefix of your web app path, then you might have to set it explicitly:

```
session_set_cookie_params($expiretime, '/');
```

inside every script before calling session_start()